# Input File upload success?

Tags: javascript, jquery, file, form-submit

I have a quite complex form that has one "file" input, such as:

```
<input type="file" />
```

Is it possible to trigger some kind of "upload successful" with JS, so after user uploads the file the whole form submits itself?

Comment: What do you mean by "user uploads the file the whole form submits itself?"?

Comment: On a syncronous upload, the file will be uploaded on the actual submit event. Look in to `XmlHttpRequest2`

Comment: Okay, so I have a complex form and user can fill the whole form OR upload a file (which is then processed in the back). Right now user is able to fill the form, then eventually upload the file then he has to click "Submit" to send the form. I want the form to be submitted automatically just after user uploads the file.

Comment: Listen for the file input fields change event and trigger the submit programatically.

Comment: Can you paste the jquery ajax code which you use for upoading the file . then it would be more easy for us to analyse and suggest you a work around.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can upload your files asynchronously (if you want you may upload multiple files).
So for example:

```
<input type="file" class="js-file-upload" multiple>
```

After creating input tag, you can listen to change event

```
$(".js-file-upload").on("change", function(e){
 var files = e.target.files;
 // your own logic to filter files etc.
 // upload your file
});
```

After all this you can listen to upload finish event (to submit after loading all files for example). 
Javascript XMLHttpRequest object provides two events: **upload.progress** and **load**. So use it ))

Pseudocode from my project:

```
file.on("upload.progress", function(e){
  //value show progress
  var value = Math.floor(e.loaded / e.total * 100);
});
file.on("load", function(response){ //logic });
```

Answer (score -2):

I would recommend [*jQuery File Upload*](http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/) for this purpose. The [`done`](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Options#wiki-done) callback informs the client that the file was uploaded successfully. Then you would be able to submit the corresponding form. There are many more useful callbacks (e.g. a failure callback).